# What is RAM plus and how does it impact performance?

Tags: samsung, ram, performance

So Samsung decided to factor in a feature that I have only seen work on desktop PCs called RAM plus and it's supposed to let the system use internal storage for to keep more background processes running. So does this add us more RAM and will there be a significant improvement in performance for enabling this option. Will it necessarily result in more processes running in the background being kept alive or?

Comment: Precursory search that might be helpful: [Samsung Support - What is RAM Plus and How to Use It?](https://www.samsung.com/sg/support/mobile-devices/what-is-ram-plus-and-how-to-use-it/), [Android Authority - Need more RAM on your Samsung phone? Samsung makes it (kind of) possible.](https://www.androidauthority.com/samsung-ram-plus-3019757/), [Android Police - Samsung RAM Plus slowing your phone down? Here's how to disable it](https://www.androidpolice.com/samsung-ram-plus-phone-how-to-disable/)

Comment: Thanks Andrew T. Let me check the links out.